# How to make an RxJS subscription with an async function serialize the onNext calls?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

This is a followup for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816172/is-it-safe-to-subscribe-to-an-observable-with-an-async-function).

So RxJS is calling my async function with the next event bebore the previous one has completed as soon as I await in my async method.

I need to serialize the calls to this async function.

I have understood from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38642593/15186) to a similar question that I need to move my async function away from subscribe and use concatMap.

Right now my code does not compile with the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'concatMap' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

My code (trying to adjust):

1/ the new subscription code (won't compile):

```
this.emitter = fromEventPattern(this.addHandler, this.removeHandler, (err, char) => [err, char]); <= unchanged
this.rxSubscription = this.rxSubscription = this.emitter.concatMap(value:any => this.handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor(value)).subscribe(); <= concatMap does not exist on type Observable<any>
```

2/ the async function for your information:

```
       handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor = async (arr: any[]): Promise<void> => {
   ...
   await someMethodAsync();
   ...
}
```

concatMap should be used on another type of source but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators'` then `this.emitter.pipe( concatMap() ).subscribe()`. Thats assuming you have rxjs v. `^6.0.0`. Again, [an example using pipe and concatMap with a promise](https://observable-playground.github.io/gist/201babaf39591ca11c00d9224e78efd0)

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kos stated, in Rxjs v6, pipeable operators became the norm, moving away from chaining everything together with `.`. 
I assume since you're using `fromEventPattern`, instead of `Observable.fromEventPattern` that you are using rxjs v6+, in which case, you need to wrap `concatMap()` inside a `pipe()`.

```
this.rxSubscription = this.emitter.pipe(concatMap(value:any => this.handleUpdatedValuesComingFromSensor(value))).subscribe()
```

Comment: Hello, Chase, welcome to SO! While its important to give a precise solution, its also very valuable to add an explanation of your solution: why and how it works. You can edit your answer to add more textual context to your solution.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the lack of explanation. I will add some more context to clarify. I did not see your comment before posting, I apologize if I took the solution from you.